# AWS route 53 subdomain/ s3 bucket with cloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have two websites (https://website1.com and https://website2.com) hosted on two different AWS account:

- I'm using route 53 with a hosted zone for https://website1.com, which
  is hosted on s3.
- https://website2.com is hosted on s3 with a
  cloudFront.

What I want to achieve: I want https://website2.com to be displayed on https://subdomain.website1.com.

So far I have defined a simple record in route 53 with the following:

- name: subdomain.website1.com
- type: CNAME
- Route traffic to: IP address
- Value: ???

What should I add in the value field? The IP of the cloudFront used to display https://website2.com?

Comment: dont route to IP. CNAME can point to domain itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each CloudFront distribution has a name, you can grab it from CloudFront object.
take the cname and use it for the route53 record